# Using Google Sheet's Filter function, clarification needed

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, range, unique

I am trying to filter some information with 2 conditionals (something is true and something else is >0)

Independently things work just fine:

```
=unique(filter(
    indirect($A$1&"!$E$3:E"),
    indirect($A$1&"!$C$3:C")=TRUE
))
```

gives me a list of things that are true, and

```
=unique(filter(
    indirect($A$1&"!$E$3:E"),
    indirect($A$1&"!$J$3:J")>0
))
```

gives me a list of things that are >0.

When i try to combine them, like this

```
=unique(filter(
        indirect($A$1&"!$E$3:E"),
        indirect($A$1&"!$C$3:C")=TRUE,
        indirect($A$1&"!$J$3:J")>0
))
```

I get an error `No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.`

What am i missing please?

PS: It goes without saying that I do indeed have things that are both true and are > 0

Comment: formula you use looks ok. can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @player0, interesting ... things appear to work fine in the new XLS. I wonder if it's a matter of format or the like .... will troubleshoot. Still, however, independently things work fine. Weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for non-english locale it would be:

```
=unique(filter(
        indirect($A$1&"!$E$3:E");
        indirect($A$1&"!$C$3:C")=TRUE;
        indirect($A$1&"!$J$3:J")>0))
```